# jedi-vim how to jump to the definition of a function in other file

Tags: vim, jedi-vim

I am new to `jedi-vim`, and I do not know how to jump the definition of a function in other file.

The [`jedi-vim`'s doc](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) is:

The following are parts of them:

> NOTE: subject to change!
>
> let g:jedi#goto_command = "<*leader*>d"
>
> let g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = "<*leader*>g"
>
> let g:jedi#goto_definitions_command = ""
>
> let g:jedi#documentation_command = "K"
>
> let g:jedi#usages_command = "<*leader*>n"
>
> let g:jedi#completions_command = "<*C-Space*>"
>
> let g:jedi#rename_command = "<*leader*>r"

And I wonder what are `<leader>` and `<C-Space>` mean and how to use these commands on VIM

Comment: Could you please change the title of your post, since this question is about invoking jedi-vim commands, and not about jumping to a definition in another file.

Comment: change the title or the content.

Comment: @Jason, Could you tell me the reason why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<leader>` is a placeholder: when vim registers a mapping containing that string it replaces it with the current value of the `mapleader` variable.

If you didn't set that variable explicitly, `<leader>` is replaced with `\` by default and those mapping are supposed to be read as `\d`, `\g`, etc. That is, press <kbd>\</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd> in rapid succession.

`:help mapleader` tells you how to set `<leader>` to something else if you don't like `\`.

`<C-Space>` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

See `:help key-notation`, `:help mapleader`.

Comment: <C-Space> means also Ctrl + Space.

Comment: @DaveHalter, no idea why I put a `c`, there, instead of `Space`.

Comment: does this answer the question, which is about jumping to a definition in another file?

Comment: No, that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to jump to the file of function definition is this command:

`<leader>d`

It is the first command listed in your list of mappings.